# How to call image from JSON that has local path in React Native

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native, jsx, prefix

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
ScrollView,
StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import CarDetail from '../components/CarDetail';

class CarList extends Component {
state = { cars: [] };

componentDidMount() {
axios.get('https://www.website.com/ajx/home_ajx/lister')
.then(response => this.setState({ cars: response.data.data[0]['S1'] 
}));

//Add an if statement here to notify the user when the request fails
}

renderCars() {
return this.state.cars.map(model => 
  <CarDetail key={model.title} modelprop={model} /> 
);
}

render() {
console.log(this.state);

return (
  <ScrollView>
    {this.renderCars()}
  </ScrollView>
);
}  
}

export default CarList;
```

And the image path in the JSON file is as below:

"image": "data/models/peugeot-2008-138twf_600X400_.jpg",

Below is where I'm calling the image in another component

```
const CarDetail = ({ modelprop }) => {
const { image } = modelprop;
return (
<Card>
<CardSection>
<View>
  <Image style={imageStyle} 
  source={{ uri: props.modelprop.image }} 
  />
</View>
```

I believe I need to use some kind of prefix maybe in my Global.js which I couldn't find or figure out.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly like your code has a bug:

```
const CarDetail = ({ modelprop }) => {
  const { image } = modelprop;
  return (
    <View>
      <Image
       style={imageStyle} 
       source={{ uri: image }} 
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

If the `image` is something like `data/models/peugeot-2008-138twf_600X400_.jpg`, you should use `${Global.imageUrlPrefix}${image}` to concat all.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I didn't include the whole code it actually doesn't have a bug. And what will be the imageUrlPrefix where and how do I define that?